# Какие знаки препинания поставить на месте пропусков:

Tags: пунктуация

Какие знаки препинания поставить на месте пропусков:

1. "Внезапно зазвучала пугающая мелодия, от_чего по телу пробежали мурашки() – и так же внезапно прекратилась."
2. "Она засмеялась (можно ли здесь поставить тире?) даже её смех был нежным."
3. "Он отступал назад() до тех пор, пока..."
4. "Я() правда() должна уходить, меня ждут."
5. "- Но я не могу...  - Что() значит() ты не можешь?!"

Comment: Желательно, чтобы вы предложили свои варианты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внезапно зазвучала пугающая мелодия, отчего по телу пробежали мурашки, – и так же внезапно прекратилась.

Она засмеялась - даже её смех был нежным (присоединение/распространение).

Он отступал назад до тех пор, пока...

Я, правда, должна уходить, меня ждут (вводное слово). Я прАвда должна уходить, меня ждут (частица).

Но я не могу... Что значит - ты не можешь?! БСП, пропущено "это".